# How to detect that an Excel cell has been changed by formula and write data to a CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, calculated-field

I have an Excel file that is updated every few seconds by an application. Using the data delivered by the application, several cells in the worksheet (called "TSdata") are calculated using various formulae. If the value of a specific cell (B41) changes, the macro should write the contents of the worksheet to a CSV file.
With the help of one of the guys on superuser.com, I created a version based on Worksheet_Change that worked perfectly if the content of the cell was manually updated. I created a version using Worksheet_Calculate that I expected to work the same way when the cell value was changed by the formula. 
This is the code I used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Worksheets(“TSdata”).Range(“B41”).Value<>prevval Then
    Call ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV
End If
prevval = Worksheets(“TSdata”).Range(“B41”).Value
End Sub


Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()
Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TSdata")     'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       'Possibly overwrite without asking
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\TSCSV\TSCSV1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
FileCopy "C:\TSCSV\TSCSV1.csv", "C:\ChartInfo\Data\TSCSV2.csv"
End Sub
```

I know from the earlier test using a manual update that the Public Sub works OK (It's copied from another query regarding writing CSV files) but when I launch the macro, it seems to attempt multiple updates (the screen blinks several times) and then crashes Excel. So, obviously something in the Private Sub is incorrect, but I've based it on other responses to similar questions, so I'm at a loss to figure out what's wrong/missing.
Note: the FileCopy at the end of the Public Sub is so that another program can work on the CSV without disrupting the Excel updates.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are your quotes really like `“”`? If so, change them to `"`

Comment: No, the quotes are ". I was using Word when I wrote out the original text. Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Copying a worksheet to no location creates a new workbook with a single worksheet that is a copy of the original.

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()
    Dim fn1 As String, fn2 As String

    fn1 = "C:\TSCSV\TSCSV1.csv"
    fn2 = "C:\ChartInfo\Data\TSCSV2.csv"

    'copying a ws to no location creates a new workbook with a single worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TSdata").Copy     'Sheet to export as CSV

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False          'Possibly overwrite without asking
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=fn1, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    On Error Resume Next
    If CBool(Len(Dir(fn2))) Then Kill fn2
    FileCopy fn1, fn2
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this has the same effect as before - it generates multiple new VBAProjects as soon as it hits the line
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TSdata").Copy
Eventually Excel stops working.
Is it possibly linked to the fact that another program is simultaneously updating the worksheet, providing the data that generates the calculated value in the cell being monitored for changes?